# Change checkout tooltip to string

Tags: magento2, checkout, plugin, radio-fields, tooltip

I am working with a custom plugin in Magento 2 that adds two radio fields after all the other inputs. Here is a photo of what it looks like:

[image]

When you click on the question mark, a tooltip shows up with some text. I want that text to be displayed right next to "Is Tax Exempt" after the radio buttons instead of being a tooltip, so that the message is always displayed. Here is the current code:

```
<?php

namespace Module\Checkout\Plugin\Block;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $context, $result)
    {
        $newFields = [
            'is_residential' => 'Is Residential',
            'is_tax_exempt'  => 'Is Tax Exempt',
        ];

        $i = 1;
        foreach ($newFields as $newField => $newFieldLabel) {
            $customField = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/checkbox-set',
                'config' => [
                    // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                    'customEntry' => null,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox-set',
                ],
                'additionalClasses' => 'custom-field-radio',
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.' . $newField,
                'label' => $newFieldLabel,
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'sortOrder' => 200 + $i,
                'validation' => [
                    'required-entry' => true
                ],
                'filterBy' => null,
                'customEntry' => null,
                'visible' => true,
                'options' => [
                    ['value' => '1', 'label' => 'Yes'],
                    ['value' => '0', 'label' => 'No'],
                ],
                'valueMap' => [
                    '1' => true,
                    '0' => false
                ]
            ];

            if ($newField == 'is_tax_exempt') {
                $customField['tooltip']['description'] = 'Text I want to display next to radio buttons';
            }

            $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$newField] = $customField;

            $i++;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
$customField['config']['tooltip']['description'] = 'Text I want to display next to radio buttons';
```

Comment: Did nothing, the tooltip is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line after dataScope

> 'description' => __('custom text'),